# Error while setting Liferay and running its server in Liferay Development Studio

Tags: java, tomcat, liferay-7

I am new to liferay and started with downloading Liferay Development Studio Bundle and server.I am getting below error while adding a new server and running it.Please help me outfor this

```
22-Apr-2020 01:34:28.926 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Server initialization in [924] milliseconds
Loading jar:file:/C:/Liferay/liferay-ce-portal-7.3.1-ga2/tomcat-9.0.33/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/portal-impl.jar!/system.properties
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by com.liferay.petra.reflect.ReflectionUtil (file:/C:/Liferay/liferay-ce-portal-7.3.1-ga2/tomcat-9.0.33/lib/ext/com.liferay.petra.reflect.jar) to method java.lang.Object.clone()
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of com.liferay.petra.reflect.ReflectionUtil
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
Loading jar:file:/C:/Liferay/liferay-ce-portal-7.3.1-ga2/tomcat-9.0.33/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/portal-impl.jar!/portal.properties
Loading file:/C:/Liferay/liferay-ce-portal-7.3.1-ga2/portal-ext.properties
Loading file:/C:/Liferay/liferay-ce-portal-7.3.1-ga2/tomcat-9.0.33/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/classes/portal-developer.properties
2020-04-22 01:34:33.209 INFO  [main][PortalContextLoaderListener:139] JVM arguments: -Dcatalina.base=C:/Liferay/liferay-ce-portal-7.3.1-ga2/tomcat-9.0.33 -Dcatalina.home=C:/Liferay/liferay-ce-portal-7.3.1-ga2/tomcat-9.0.33 -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048 -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources -Dorg.apache.catalina.security.SecurityListener.UMASK=0027 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=8099 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:/Liferay/liferay-ce-portal-7.3.1-ga2/tomcat-9.0.33/temp -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djava.util.logging.config.file=C:/Liferay/liferay-ce-portal-7.3.1-ga2/tomcat-9.0.33/conf/logging.properties -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager -Dorg.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.ENABLE_CLEAR_REFERENCES=false -Duser.timezone=GMT -Xmx2560m
22-Apr-2020 01:34:33.748 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class [com.liferay.portal.spring.context.PortalContextLoaderListener]
    java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.context.PortalContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(PortalContextLoaderListener.java:255)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4690)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5151)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:717)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:690)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:705)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:631)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1831)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptors(HostConfig.java:526)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:425)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1576)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:309)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:423)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:366)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:936)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:841)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:421)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:930)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:633)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:343)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:474)
    Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
        at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
        at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:662)
        at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:770)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.storagemanager.StorageManager.updateTable(StorageManager.java:511)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.storagemanager.StorageManager.open(StorageManager.java:708)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.storage.Storage.getChildStorageManager(Storage.java:2011)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.storage.Storage.getInfoInputStream(Storage.java:2028)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.storage.Storage.<init>(Storage.java:216)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.storage.Storage.createStorage(Storage.java:151)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxContainer.<init>(EquinoxContainer.java:69)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.launch.Equinox.<init>(Equinox.java:31)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.launch.EquinoxFactory.newFramework(EquinoxFactory.java:24)
        at com.liferay.portal.bootstrap.ModuleFrameworkImpl.initFramework(ModuleFrameworkImpl.java:278)
        at com.liferay.portal.module.framework.ModuleFrameworkUtilAdapter.initFramework(ModuleFrameworkUtilAdapter.java:64)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.context.PortalContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(PortalContextLoaderListener.java:243)
        ... 41 more
22-Apr-2020 01:34:33.749 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
22-Apr-2020 01:34:34.112 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Context [] startup failed due to previous errors
2020-04-22 01:34:34.274 ERROR [main][PortalContextLoaderListener:114] java.lang.NullPointerException
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.DirectServletRegistryUtil.clearServlets(DirectServletRegistryUtil.java:25)
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.context.PortalContextLoaderListener.contextDestroyed(PortalContextLoaderListener.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:4737)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5401)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:257)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:187)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:690)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:705)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:631)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1831)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptors(HostConfig.java:526)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:425)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1576)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:309)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:423)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:366)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:936)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:841)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:421)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:930)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:633)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:343)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:474)
2020-04-22 01:34:34.287 ERROR [main][PortalContextLoaderListener:114] java.lang.NullPointerException
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.deploy.hot.HotDeployUtil.reset(HotDeployUtil.java:50)
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.context.PortalContextLoaderListener.contextDestroyed(PortalContextLoaderListener.java:129)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:4737)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5401)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:257)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:187)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:690)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:705)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:631)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1831)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptors(HostConfig.java:526)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:425)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1576)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:309)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:423)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:366)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:936)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:841)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:421)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:930)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:633)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:343)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:474)
2020-04-22 01:34:34.302 ERROR [main][PortalBeanLocatorUtil:66] BeanLocator is null
22-Apr-2020 01:34:34.304 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop Exception sending context destroyed event to listener instance of class [com.liferay.portal.spring.context.PortalContextLoaderListener]
    com.liferay.portal.kernel.bean.BeanLocatorException: BeanLocator is not set
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.bean.PortalBeanLocatorUtil.locate(PortalBeanLocatorUtil.java:68)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.context.PortalContextLoaderListener.closeDataSource(PortalContextLoaderListener.java:385)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.context.PortalContextLoaderListener.contextDestroyed(PortalContextLoaderListener.java:142)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:4737)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5401)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:257)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:187)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:717)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:690)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:705)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:631)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1831)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptors(HostConfig.java:526)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:425)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1576)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:309)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:423)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:366)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:936)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:841)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:421)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:930)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:633)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:343)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:474)
22-Apr-2020 01:34:34.365 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in [5,435] milliseconds
```

Comment: Please add steps you took to configure the server, as well as all involved versions. Especially: Did you use one of the LTS-JDKs to run the server? Try JDK 11, rather than the bleeding edge.

Comment: Thanks Olaf for responding on my post.I got the problem,it was with downloaded bundle of Tomcat.Mistakenly I downloaded .tar instead of .zip.